# Datetime variable "tics" one hour

Tags: c#, sql, debugging, datetime

I have a strange problem with my code(or rather, code of someone else). I'm debugging and trying to figure out why our time shows up wrong.

Anyhow, this is the code that prints the time:

```
                                              Wrong value gets returned   
                                                           v 
[...].text="updated: "+TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(OurClass.FetchTime("TableName"), siteTimeZone).ToLongTimeString();
```

And this is the method that gets called:

```
SqlCommand cmd=getConnection();

cmd.CommandText="Procedure_to_fetch_time";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table", tableName);

object o=cmd.ExecuteScalar();

closeConnection(cmd);

if(o==null) 
{
    return DateTime.MinValue;
}
return DateTime.Parse(o.ToString());
                      ^ here it's correct
```

I've debugged it and checked every single operation that might change the value(all the conversions and stuff) and when the method returns the value, it is correct. But when it arrives, 1 hour has "passed" and the time is now wrong ...

Anyone know what might cause this?

---

**Edit:**

For responding the comments:

- The value is changed before `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` happes.
- Why object? No idea, not my code.
- `o.ToString()` is `"1900-01-01 00:00:00"`.
- `DateTime.Parse` also returns `"1900-01-01 00:00:00"`.
- Database is using `smalldatetime`.
- Database is in the same timezone of client.

Comment: Why are you using `object` and not `DateTime` directly? What is the value of `o.ToString()`? What is the result of `DateTime.Parse` on that string?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` that's adding an hour?

Comment: daylight savings would be my initial guess

Comment: TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc will take into account the timezone that the host machine is running under. Have you checked the machine timezone along with any daylight savings that might effect it?

Comment: Is your database in a different timezone from the client app?  What datatype are you using in the DB to store the date time?

Comment: The value is changed before TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc happes. Why object? no idea, not my code. o.ToString() is "1900-01-01 00:00:00" DateTime.Parse is the same ("1900-01-01 00:00:00"). Database is using smalldatetime. Database is in the same timezone

Comment: If the value is correct where you say it is, then how can the `ToString()` operation return what looks like `new DateTime()`?

Comment: Becasue the time that is stored in our database is just for testing atm. It's stored as "1900-01-01 00:00:00"

Comment: If you split that code and put the result of `OurClass.FetchTime("TableName")` into a new variable, and use that in the `ConvertTimeFromUtc` call, what is the value of that new variable and what is the result?

Comment: @DonBoitnott - a `new DateTime()` would return year "0001", not "1900".

Comment: @HansKesting Ahhh yes, that's right, isn't it.  I must be thinking about SQL Server minimum or something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DateTime` object has a `Kind` property. This property says whether the data should be interpreted in UTC (`DateTimeKind.Utc`) or in the local time zone (`DateTimeKind.Local`), or whether it is unknown (`DateTimeKind.Unspecified`).

You should use the overload of `DateTimeParse` that takes a `DateTimeStyles` parameter, and specify  `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` or `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal`.